# Minimum shifting in an array of integers so their difference is >= k

Tags: algorithm

I was asked to implement an algorithm that takes as input the following:

-A sorted array of integers a, for example a=[0,0,0,0,0,2,4,4,4,4,4].  If it helps the actual input is given as two arrays from which the first gives us the integer and the second the times that each integer of the first appears. For our example [0,2,4],[5,1,5].

-An integer k.

and returns an array b of unique reals(two decimal digits) whose consecutive elements differ at least k and the maximum difference |a[i]-b[i]| is the minimum possible. Both arrays a and b are sorted.

So far I have turned the two given arrays in one , as I described earlier, and after several loops manage to make array a , a sorted array with unique elements following the steps below:

-for each multiple appearance of an integer , e.g. 5 times 0 , I shift them the minimum possible distance : let’s say k=2 then [0,0,0,0,0]->[-4,-2,0,2,4].

-then I sort the array in order to find the multiple appearances that caused from the shifting.

-repeat these two steps until the array has only unique elements.
If I had a way to move my last array’s elements to their requested position (so their final difference was >=k) , I assume that the difference of the later to the starting array would by my requested shifts.

My whole thought may be wrong or too slow but I have reached a dead end with this problem, so any help would be great !! Thank you in advance !!!

P.S. I include a small example of the exercise to make the whole thing more clear :
K=2, a=[0,1], b=[3,1] (->c= [0,0,0,1])  so our result should be [-2,5 , -0,5 , 1,5 , 2,5] which makes the maximum minimum shift 2,50.

Comment: just for future reference, no need for homework tag / do not use

Comment: Can you clearly define what you mean by a 'shift' in this context.

Comment: Should the result array (after the "shifts") be sorted? `[0, 0, 0, 1]` can be turned into `[-1, 1, -1, 1]` with minimal "shift" of 1.

Comment: @cmh Shifts are the differences between given array and aswer

Comment: @anatolyg The array has to contain unique elements, hence the result [-2,5 , -0,5 , 1,5 , 2,5]

Answer (score 0):

if `max-min <= k*n`, then array `b` is

```
M+0, M+k, M+2k, ..., M+(n-1)k
```

where `M` satisfies

```
|max-M-k(n-1)| = |min-M|.
```

All you need to 
be concerned about is the first and last elements of 
array `a` as long as your consecutive array `b` elements 
differ by `k` and they have to for the optimal result in this case.

if `max-min > k*n` then it is much easier: 
set

```
k=(max-min)/(n-1)
```

satisfying the decimal digits in your condition and set `b[0]=min`. Add `k` to every next element of `b`.